# Win32: When SeCreateTokenPrivilege required?

Tags: windows, winapi, nt

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/create-a-token-object) say `SeCreateTokenPrivilege` is used

> when the process uses `NtCreateToken()` or **other token-creation APIs**.

What is the **other token-creation APIs** (that may require `SeCreateTokenPrivilege`)?

Comment: `NtCreateTokenEx` and `NtCreateLowBoxToken` (not require SeCreateTokenPrivilege )? set `TokenLinkedToken` require

Comment: @RbMm post answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to RbMm's reply:

`NtCreateTokenEx` and `NtCreateLowBoxToken` (not require SeCreateTokenPrivilege), set `TokenLinkedToken` require